# В iOS не работает unwind когда вернулся с другой апликации?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Вот такая проблемма - у меня приложение с навигацией внутри (реализова вручную - не ползуюсь UINavigationGontroller). В одном из контроллеров (глубоко в иерархии) я должен стартовать другое приложение (оно реализовано другой компаней). Я стартую ето приложение. Потом возвращаюсь обратно в мое приложение (через кнопку - кнопка назад для возврата в мое приложение). После возврата unwind segue перестает работать. Примечательно что если я вернусь в мое приложение с помощью авоматического линка генерированного iOS unwind segue работает. Какие то предложения?

Пояснение: другое приложение может открыватся из произвольного проложения (не только моего, но и других, у которых реализована ета опция). Оттуда они позволяют вернутся обратно использую кнопку "назад". Но ето специфическая кнопка, а не автоматическая ссылка генерируемая операционной системой.

Comment: Что значит "возвращаюсь обратно в мое приложение (через кнопку)"?

Comment: Да, @VAndrJ. Мне нужно открыть внешнее приложение, после чего оттуда вернутся в мое проложение используя кнопку "назад" (но ето не автоматическая ссылка от Apple).

Comment: Я бы проверил класс который отвечает за навигацию, не удаляется ли он.

Comment: Спасибо за предложение, но я не знаю как ето сделат, можете какую нибудь подсказку где искать как ето делается, @AndreyIskamov?

Comment: если вы знаете какой класс отвечает за навигацию просто добавьте туда  -(void)dealloc{  NSLog(@"Dealock"); } в m файл и посмотрите в консоль если при возврате будет сообщение в консоли, то объект удален если нет то проблема в другом

Comment: Большое спасибо, @AndreyIskamov ! Не знам что у делалекации есть событие `dealloc`!

Comment: напишите что там получится, самому интересно что же там у вас